# Type matches only inside a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in haskell, and trying to implement the Church encoding for natural numbers, as explained in [this guide](http://archive.is/dumJ2).

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Chur = Chr (forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a))

zero :: Chur
zero = Chr (\x y -> y)

-- church to int
c2i :: Chur -> Integer
c2i (Chr cn) = cn (+ 1) 0

-- this works
i1 = c2i zero
-- this doesn't
i2 = zero (+ 1) 0
```

For `i2` I get a type mismatch:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> t’
            with actual type ‘Chur’
Relevant bindings include i2 :: t (bound at test.hs:14:1)
The function ‘zero’ is applied to two arguments,
but its type ‘Chur’ has none
In the expression: zero (+ 1) 0
In an equation for ‘i2’: i2 = zero (+ 1) 0
```

How come `Chur` can take arguments when wrapped in a function, but can't without it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Chur` doesn't take any arguments when wrapped in the function - the function wrapped in `Chur` does:

```
c2i (Chr cn) = cn (+ 1) 0
```

Here, `cn` is the function wrapped inside a `Chur`.

You can use the substitution method to see what's happening:

```
    c2i zero
==> c2i (Chr (\x y -> y))
==> (\x y -> y) (+ 1) 0
==> 0
```

But

```
    zero (+ 1) 0
==> (Chr (\x y -> y)) (+ 1) 0
```

which doesn't work since `(Chr (\x y -> y))` is not a function.

If you'd written

```
c2i :: Chur -> Integer
c2i cn = cn (+ 1) 0
```

you would have seen a similar error.

Comment: Thx, any idea how to print these substitutions?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650044/show-substitutions-in-ghci

Comment: @dimid You type them on your keyboard, like I did.