# Show substitutions in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

How can I see substitutions of variable names to their values in haskell?
e.g.

```
    c2i zero
==> c2i (Chr (\x y -> y))
==> (\x y -> y) (+ 1) 0
==> 0
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644918/165753).

Comment: I *wish* there was a way to do this...

Comment: Not full-featured, but... : http://chrisuehlinger.com/LambdaBubblePop/ and https://stevekrouse.github.io/hs.js/ (even if they are not completely bug-free...)

Comment: also, http://joerg.endrullis.de/lambdaCalculator.html